# App authentication stuck in an infinite redirect loop

Tags: facebook, authentication, loops

My app gets stuck in an infinite redirect loop, because $facebook->getUser(); always returns 0. I've read through many threads here on stackoverflow and other sites as well concerning similar issues, but no solution found so far. I use the following code to authenticate:

```
//
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => APP_ID,
  'secret' => APP_SECRET,
  'cookie' => true,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array (
      "scope" => "user_likes,email,user_hometown,publish_stream",
      "redirect_uri" => "https://www.facebook.com/pages/erdekelnehu/268142359907805?sk=app_175080802604575"
      ));
  die ('<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href="' . $loginUrl . '";</script>');
}
```

After some debugging I found that being redirected from the oauth dialog my app dosen't have a signed_request. $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST are all empty arrays. 
$facebook->getLoginUrl returns the following Url:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=175080802604575&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2Ferdekelnehu%2F268142359907805%3Fsk%3Dapp_175080802604575&state=3c0d5802c89e913368ea814d49792454&scope=user_likes%2Cemail%2Cuser_hometown%2Cpublish_stream

I tried calling $facebook->getLoginUrl without the redirect_uri parameter, leaving it to fb to figure out the correct return url:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=175080802604575&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ferdekelne.hu%2Fdroidtv%2F&state=3c0d5802c89e913368ea814d49792454&scope=user_likes%2Cemail%2Cuser_hometown%2Cpublish_stream

The two urls are not the same and neither one is working. The second url redirects to a fb error page saying that some error occured and "We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."
So can it be a fb bug, or am I doing something wrong? Any ideas would be appreciated, beacuse after 6 hours of debugging I've completely run out of them.

Comment: Checks 1.Have you correctly configured your website url in Apps registration .(Note .www.example.com is not equal to example.com).2.Are you requesting from same domain as registered.?

Comment: I finally managed to sort it out. I had to append index.php to my page tab url on the app settings page. Now everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

Just got a similar problem, and it was fixed by updating the spaces in directory name (where application was placed) into URL-compatible chars i.e. %20. It worked like a charm.